# Kotlin runBlocking for synchronous legacy calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin-coroutines, interrupted-exception

I need to interface Coroutine-heavy code with legacy Java code in Android. At one place I need to call a suspend method that queries something from a Room database from Android's main thread. And even though this is highly disregarded (I know, I know), I have to make this call (for now at least) block the main thread.

Problem is, `runBlocking { mySuspensionMethod() }` might trigger an `InterruptedException`, as the [docs state](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html):

> If [the] blocked thread [of runBlocking] is interrupted (see Thread.interrupt), then the coroutine job is cancelled and this runBlocking invocation throws InterruptedException.

I re-read the handling of `InterruptedException`s again and again and clearly you should only do one of two things, throw the exception further or set the interrupted flag for your own thread (`Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`).

Now I guess handling the exception is a dead-end, as I don't want to throw the exception further (which will result in an app crash) nor do I want to interrupt Android's main thread (which results in god knows what), so the question is, is there any other API that I could use to just make this blocking call and return a result?

Comment: "nor do I want to interrupt Android's main thread" - That exception implies something else has interrupted the main thread, so either the interrupt happens and you need to handle it, or it never happens and you can ignore it

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong in doing just nothing. If someone interrupts the main thread that means it may throw `InterruptedException` in many different places in your code, not only in `runBlocking()`. Because this is the way how interruptions are handled - by throwing exceptions that propagate from top to bottom. Most probably, this thread is never interrupted.